# The number of electors were/was?

Tags: grammar

please help me in understanding this doubt. My brain says 'were' but some stupid online rule says was'

Comment: you're right. it's 'was'

Comment: Can you give the entire sentence for context?

Answer (score 0):

You want to know the number of electors. What **was** the number?

What's confusing you, is that the plural word *electors* comes immediately before the verb. It can be difficult to match *was* with *the number* a) because of the distance between the words and b) because of the aforesaid intervening plural word.

So, the correct start to that sentence is:

> The number of electors **was** [large, high, etc.]

since you would also say:

> The number **was** [large, high, etc.]

but saying:

> The electors **were** [large, high, etc.]

completely changes the meaning, because of the change of subject and not because of the different verb conjugation.

You can work out the rule for yourself by simplifying the phrase until the answer becomes clear.